# Retrieve data from a form with GET method using symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, php-5.3, symfony-2.3

I can't retrieve data from my form, I tried differents ways but no result. My repository :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('min_price', 'text', array('mapped' => false, 'label' => 'De la :', 'attr'=>
                                       array(
                                            'placeholder'=>'Pretul minim',
                                            'class'=>'form-control')))
            ->add('max_price', 'text', array('mapped' => false, 'label' => 'Pina la :' , 'attr'=>
                                        array(
                                            'placeholder'=>'Pretul maxim',
                                            'class'=>'form-control')))


            )
    ;
}
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    parent::setDefaultOptions($resolver);
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        // avoid to pass the csrf token in the url (but it's not protected anymore)
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return '';
}
```

My controller :

```
public function showCategoryAction($id, $page, Request $request){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repositoryProduct = $em->getRepository('ShopDesktopBundle:Product');

    $category = $em->getRepository('ShopDesktopBundle:Category')->findOneById($id);
    if (!$category) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Category not found.');
    }
    $aFilter = array();

    $entity = new Product();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $entity,array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('show_product_category',array("id" => $id, "name" => $category->getCategoryLink(), "page" => $page )), //Your url to generate
        'method' => 'GET'
    ));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $aFilter['iMinPrice'] = $form["min_price"]->getData();
    $aFilter['iMaxPrice'] = $form["max_price"]->getData();
    print_r($aFilter);

    //Searchs products
    $aProducts          = $repositoryProduct->getProductsOrderByDateDesc($id,null,$aFilter);
    if (!$aProducts) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Products not found.');
    }

    //Create pagination
    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $aProducts,
        $page,
        3
    );
    //Send data to view
    return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle:Category:category.html.twig',array(
        'category'          => $category,
        'pagination'        => $pagination,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

My view :

```
<form action="{{ path('show_product_category',{ 'id':category.getId(), 'name':category.getCategoryLink() }) }}" method="get" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
                        <div class="accordion-group">
                            <div class="accordion-heading">
                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#toggleOne">
                                    <em class="icon-minus icon-fixed-width"></em>Pret
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="toggleOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                                <div class="accordion-inner">
                                    {{ form_widget(form) }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary marg-left-20" value="Cautare"/>
                    </form>
```

The view :

```
show_product_category:
path:     /{id}/{name}/{page}
defaults: { _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:Category:showCategory, page: 1}
requirements:
    id:  \d+
    page: \d+
    _method:  GET|POST
```

So the problem is that I can't retrieve data from thi form. For all situations $aFilter is empty. If for example I put in the view in form POST method the filter is with data from form. My url look like this : 
?min_price=10&max_price=50.
Help me please. Thx in advance.Exist a solution??

Comment: Could you try `$form->get("min_price")->getData();`?

Comment: Not work, the array is empty

Answer (score 2):

I would not set the form method as `GET`, just do not specify a method and it will default to `POST`, which is the usual way to submit a form.

Then handle the form submission in your `Controller` when the method is `POST` - like this:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid() {
        $aFilter['iMinPrice'] = $form->get('min_price')->getData();
        $aFilter['iMaxPrice'] = $form->get('max_price')->getData();
    }
}
```

More information on how to handle form submissions in Symfony2 [**here**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions).

---

If you really need the form method to be `GET`, you should be able to get the query string parameters from the request:

```
$aFilter['iMinPrice'] = $request->query->get('min_price');
$aFilter['iMaxPrice'] = $request->query->get('max_price');
```

Comment: I need to be the method set as "GET" not "POST"

Comment: I tried also with $_GET but no result : 
if (isset($_GET['min_price'])){
            $test = $_GET['min_price'];
            print_r($test);
        }

Comment: I tried, but not working : the url is : ?min_price=1&max_price=111111
but aFilter is empty